# Create a specified range of random integers given the condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am creating a synthetic dataset to test a classification model. I have created 2 classes (Binary classification) targets. I want to create a random integer feature ranging values 0-40 when class=1 and 40-100 when class = 0.

This code only creates random integers, I am not sure how to put conditions on it.

`df["score_test"] = np.random.randint(0, 99, size= len(student_info))`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary expression.

```py
low, high = (0, 40) if clazz == 1 else (40, 100)
df["score_test"] = np.random.randint(low, high, size=len(student_info))
```

Comment: Notice that I used `clazz` instead of `class` here. This is because `class` is a reserved word in Python; you can't use it as a variable name.